# how to get relationshipdata from csv-file containing all relationships in single line?

Tags: python, csv, graph, relationship, networkx

I want to build relationship graph in networkx for plants. In my csv-file, all data for these plants are contained on single line for each plant. For example: plant number, plant name, companion plants, antagonists. Now I want networkx graph where plant name is in the middle and has relationship with all companion plants (each companion plant is node and main plant has edges to all of these companion plants).

For apple, data is like this:

```
1,apple,"pearl,strawberry,onion,potato","rose,cabbage,dill"
```

I know how to make graph itself because I worked on different older csv file which had plant and each companion on own line like this:

```
apple,pearl
apple,strawberry
apple,onion
apple,potato
```

I want to know how to read and get edges from this new csv which has all companions on single line separated by comma. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not split your CSV lines by `','`, as proposed in another question. Your variables in CSV contains `','` so you will get incorrect result. Just use `pandas.read_csv()`:

```
df = pd.read_csv('WAKA.csv', header=None)


    0   1       2                               3
0   1   apple   pearl,strawberry,onion,potato   rose,cabbage,dill
1   2   apple1  pearl,strawberry,onion,potato   rose,cabbage,dill
```

then iterate for rows, get column 1, split string in column 2 by `','` and add it to your networkx graph:

```
for l in df.iterrows():   # Iterate through dataframe rows
    G.add_edges_from(     # Add edges to graph
        (l[1][1], fruit)  # It is the edge: element from column 1 and splitted fruit
        for fruit in l[1][2].strip('"').split(',')  # Crop '"' and split by ','
    )
```

then just draw it:

```
nx.draw(
    G,
    node_size=3500,
    font_size=40,
    labels={n: n for n in G.nodes}
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! How can I draw only 1 fruit at time of my choosing? My csv contains a lot of data so I cannot draw all plants at once (it looks really messy).

Comment: Use loc/iloc/filter functions from pandas, like it (example): `df.iloc[lambda x: x.index % 2 == 0]` : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/frame.html#indexing-iteration

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about NetworkX, but you could maybe extract all your information into a dictionary and use that to populate your NetworkX graph.

```
plants = {}

with open('plant-data.csv') as fd:
    for line in fd:
        plant = line.split(',')

        plant_number = line[0]
        plant_name = line[1]
        plant_companions = line[2]
        plant_antagonists = line[3]

        plants[plant_name] = (plant_number, plant_companions, plant_antagonists)
```

To get all companions of `apple`, you can just access `plants["apple"][1]`.